# Themes power point 2007 - how to hide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Does anybody know how to hides the themes in PowerPoint 2007?

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the .thmx files in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 12\"

to be able to restore, you can move or rename instead of delete. moving to a sub-folder works OK, or you could instead change the extension to something like hide_thmx.

Comment: thanks for the idea, if I delete it, can I still have it back? and if yes, how?